# In topological group left and right multiplication are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

From Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group): The inversion operation on a topological group $G$ is a homeomorphism from $G$ to itself. Likewise, if $a$ is any element of $G$, then left or right multiplication by $a$ yields a homeomorphism $G \rightarrow G$.

Maybe it is trivial, but I am not able to find argments, why left and right multiplication are homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the axioms for a topological group says that, for every $a \in G$, the left-multiplication map $f_a : G \to G$ given by $f_a(x) = ax$ is continuous. By definition, a homeomophism of $G$ is a continuous map $f: G \to G$ with a continuous inverse. Can you give the continuos inverse for $f_a$?

Comment: Thank you, but first I thought that I must also show that $f_a$ is bijective (injective and surjective).

Comment: In fact, finding an inverse for a map (no topology needed) shows that map is injective and surjective. Are you aware of this point? If not you should try to prove it.

Comment: Yes, that is right! I did not think this way. Thank you very much!